# Avocado leaves wilting ,turning Brown

Tags: avocado, potting-soil, ph, browning

Is it effective to do a pH test only avocado plant?  What is neutral on the ph scale for the avocado plant and what is the acidic number? *Is bat or seabird guano* good for restoring a neutral pH base in the soil?

Comment: Welcome to the site, good luck to your avocado plant!

Comment: Can you add a photo of your plant showing the problem?

Comment: Are you able to show a pic of your plant?  Why do you suspect pH?    BTW, Neutral is always 7 on the pH scale.  Like most other plants, Avo trees like slightly acidic soil - about 6 - 6.5 - but I would not get hung u on it.  I doubt you want to go to 4 - that is very acidic.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it effective to do a pH test only avocado plant?

If pH is all you need to know, sure!  There are other nutrient measures you might care about, which a fuller [soil-test](/questions/tagged/soil-test) would tell you about.

> What is neutral on the ph scale for the avocado plant and what is the
> acidic number?

[Something is acidic when the pH is below 7, basic when it is above 7, and neutral at 7.](https://www.epa.gov/goldkingmine/what-ph#:%7E:text=The%20pH%20scale%20measures%20how,with%20a%20pH%20of%207.0.). The scale isn't linear, so a pH of 5 is actually 10x as acidic as a pH of 6.

[image: An image of the pH scale from 0 to 14, with 0 marked as 'Increasingly Acid' and 14 marked as 'Increasingly basic', and 7 marked as 'Neutral'. Each number is given with examples of chemicals at that pH]

[Avocados like pH in the range of 5-7](https://Avocados%20grow%20best%20with%20a%20soil%20pH%20of%205-7.%20Avocados%20are%20very%20sensitive%20to%20alkaline%20soils,%20with%20pH%20greater%20than%207), so slightly acidic to neutral soil

> Is bat or seabird guano good for restoring a neutral pH base in the
> soil?

[Bat guano is slightly basic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guano#:%7E:text=Bat%20guano%20is%20slightly%20alkaline%20with%20an%20average%20pH%20of%207.25.), I'm not sure about seabird guano.  It would make acid soil slightly more neutral.

Comment: I would imagine that seabird Guano is slightly Basic as well -  as I think it is high in Ammonia which is basic.